# How to handle error from geocode in Controller

Tags: php, laravel

In our Laravel system for pistol competitions when creating a competition we use a place or town to make a marker on a map. It works perfectly but sometimes we got an impossible name for the place and a huge error notice. The error sits for a few seconds and then disappears and one can go back and give the correct place address. I would like an error message like "Illegal address, please correct" or so.
This is the geocode part in the controller:

```
$address = $competition->contact_city; // From create.blade.php

$json = file_get_contents('https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/search.php?key=pk.0bf95265572a146a766348aff22ea4ad&q=' . $address . '&format=json');
$jsonArr = json_decode($json);

$lat = $jsonArr[0]->lat; 
$lng = $jsonArr[0]->lon;

$competition->lat = $lat;     // Stores coordinates in database
$competition->lng = $lng;
```

How can I  catch the error and give feedback when creating the competition?

Part of the error: (used bubble pool as address)

key=pk.0bf95265572a146a766348aff22ea4ad&q=sdfgsdfg&format=json): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/Api/CompetitionsController.php:204 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/vendor/sentry/sentry/lib/Raven/Breadcrumbs/ErrorHandler.php(34): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'file_get_conten...', '/var/www/app/Ht...', 204, Array) #1 [internal function]: Raven_Breadcrumbs_ErrorHandler->handleError(2, 'file_get_conten...', '/var/www/app/Ht...', 204, Array) #2 /var/www/app/Http/Controllers/Api/CompetitionsController.php(204): file_get_contents('https://eu1.loc...') #3 [internal function]: App\Http\Controllers\Api\CompetitionsController->store(Object(App\Http\Requests\CreateCompetitionRequest)) #4 /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(55): call_user_func_array(Array, Array) #5

In the create.blade.php I'm getting a huge error message with hundreds of lines where I extracted the ones above.

If needed I can put up the create blade also.

Answer (score 0):

I would say there you could do a couple things, one of those being turn off error reporting in your production server. Second could be to silence the function by using `@` in front of the function:

```
$json = @file_get_contents('https://eu1.locationiq.com/v1/search.php?key=pk.0bf95265572a146a766348aff22ea4ad&q=' . $address . '&format=json');
# Check first if the return is empty
if(!empty($json)) {
    $jsonArr = json_decode($json);
    $competition->lat = $lat = $jsonArr[0]->lat; 
    $competition->lng = $lng = $jsonArr[0]->lon;
}
else {
    # Whatever you want here for the error stuff, maybe throw an Exception?
    # This kinda depends on what you are doing for errors. I don't really
    # Know Laravel, so maybe there is some standard way to handle errors
}
```